# selecting greatest in group +N if greatest is within a range

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, greatest-n-per-group

My goal is to get all the relevant rate changes for a vendor. This means I need the most recent rate change, plus if this rate change was in the last month, I need the previous rate(s) until I get a rate outside of this month.

I have some sample data to demo this (This is relating vendors and the dates to which their pay rate changes)

```
VendorID RateEffectiveDate
2        2011-06-01
2        2012-03-15
2        2014-05-15
1        2010-07-01
1        2011-03-15
1        2013-07-01
```

What I would like is to select the greatest effective date for each VendorID + if that row is within the last month, select the next lower value.

In this case, Today being 2014-05-29 I would like to get this result:

```
VendorID RateEffectiveDate
2        2012-03-15
2        2014-05-15
1        2013-07-01
```

This way I can calculate pay rates from the previous rate over the course of the month instead of using "newest". Granted, newest will work most of the time, but this edge case is eluding me.

What I have so far is:

```
select VendorID, Max(RateEffectiveDate) RateEffectiveDate from @rateChanges
group by VendorID
```

Which only gets me the greatest date for each VendorID

```
VendorID RateEffectiveDate
2        2014-05-15
1        2013-07-01
```

but I'm missing the previous date when the pay rate changed for VendorID=2. Also while I don't anticipate the rate changing more than once a month, it could. I suspect sql might not be the place to do this, or will need to use loops to accomplish this feat.

I assume for loops this would work best, but I don't know how to "select" rows from a table with this...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178642.aspx

I've also looked at this:
[How to make a faster greatest-n-per-group query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694181/how-to-make-a-faster-greatest-n-per-group-query)

but cannot figure out how to get the previous date. I can compare and get all dates above @date, count them add 1, but I'm not sure what to do with that.

Any suggestions would be very helpful, thanks

---

**Edit**:

This is how I would solve it in pseudo

```
id int
firstOfMonth datetime := -- some value
row := first row of table
while row not null
    id := row.VendorID
    do
        take row
        move next
    while row not null and row.RateEffectiveDate > firstOfMonth and row.VendorID = id

    while row not null and row.VendorID == id
        move next
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?  Different versions support different functionality.  You shouldn't need a loop for this though.

Comment: just checked 'Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2550.0 (Intel IA-64) 
 Jun 11 2012 21:51:18 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Data Center Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0 <IA-64> (Build 6002: Service Pack 2)'

Comment: Trying out both ideas atm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to measure the change in rates, why not just use the `lag()` function?

The following gets what you want as two columns (and you can use additional logic):

```
select rc.*
from (select VendorID, RateEffectiveDate,
             lag(RateEffectiveDate) over (partition by VendorId order by RateEffectiveDate) as prevRED
      from @rateChanges
     ) rc
where RateEffectDate >= dateadd(month, -1, getdate());
```

If you don't like the two columns, then you can use `lead()` with the following logic:

```
select rc.VendorID, rc.RateEffectiveDate
from (select VendorID, RateEffectiveDate,
             lead(RateEffectiveDate) over (partition by VendorId order by RateEffectiveDate) as nextRED
      from @rateChanges
     ) rc
where nextRED is NULL or nextRED >= dateadd(month, -1, getdate());
```

EDIT:

As a note, you can implement these with correlated subqueries or `cross apply`.  For instance, the last is:

```
select rc.VendorID, rc.RateEffectiveDate
from (select VendorID, RateEffectiveDate,
             (select top 1 rc2.RateEffectiveDate
              from @ratechanges rc2
              where rc2.VendorId = rc.VendorId and
                    rc2.RateEffectiveDate > rc.RateEffectiveDate
              order by rc2.RateEffectiveDate
             ) as nextRED
      from @rateChanges rc
     ) rc
where nextRED is NULL or nextRED >= dateadd(month, -1, getdate());
```

Comment: I'm running Sql-Server 2008R2, lead and lag appear to be for 2012+ I'm sure you solution works, but I cannot verify

Comment: On the second one I'm only getting a single row for VendorID 2 and the May-15th date

Comment: very wonderful, works perfectly, now to figure out how this works too.

Comment: do you think adding RC2.VendorID = RC.VendorID to the subquery where clause would improve perf?

Comment: @ohmusama . . . Definitely.  That is equivalent to the `partition by` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your version of SQL Server supports `window functions`, you can use `row_number` and `max` to achieve your desired results:

```
with cte as (
  select t.*, 
    max(rateeffectivedate) over (partition by vendorid) maxrateeffectivedate,
    row_number() over (partition by vendorid
                       order by rateeffectivedate desc) rn
  from sampledata t
  )
select * 
from cte
where rn = 1
  or (rn = 2 and 
      maxrateeffectivedate between dateadd(month,-1,getdate()) and getdate())
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/34df6/6)

Basically this says take the highest effectivedate per vendor, and if that date is between today and a month ago, take the 2nd highest as well.

Comment: Okay I figured this out, and it still only does 1 or 2, but cannot handle 3. This is very close though, so I greatly appreciate it. The 3 edge case is extremely unlikely so probably no big deal.

Comment: @ohmusama -- not sure I understand what you mean about the 3rd case, but probably can be handled in the `where` criteria.  Perhaps I misunderstood the question.

Comment: No, it works, just in the ultra rare case, if a vendor's pay rate changes twice, trice or more in a month, I will make some erroneous pay values.